# included function not found - php

Tags: php, function, include

I've already searched for some answers but can´t find any answer that applies to my question.

```
// we are in file: file.php
include('functions.php');

$i = 0;
if($i >= countServices()) break;
[...]


// we are in file: functions.php
[...]
function countServices(){
[...]
}
```

I have already tried to include the file *functions.php* with the absolute file path but that does not work anyway.

The browser tells me:

```
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function countServices() in [...]"
```

A few days ago it worked and now...
Could you help me?

Comment: You probably checked but i have to ask: did you check the spelling of the function(call and definition) and the file name? Maybe you changed something in the past few days?

Comment: Make sure functions.php and file.php are in the same directory.

Comment: Yes, all the stuff is checked..

Comment: Hey guys!

I got it! I cut the function out and put it in the very beginning of functions.php and it works. So there had to be a mistake in a function that was in front of countServices().
And indeed there was a function where the "}" was missing.

Stupid mistake from my side -.-

But thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 4):

Try `require('functions.php')` instead of the `include` statement. Require throws an exception if the file is not found (which is what I suspect is happening here) and not a warning like `include` which can easily be swallowed if you don't have `error_reporting` set to report warnings.

Comment: Hey guys!

I got it! I cut the function out and put it in the very beginning of functions.php and it works. So there had to be a mistake in a function that was in front of countServices().
And indeed there was a function where the "}" was missing.

Stupid mistake from my side -.-

But thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the current working directory PHP is in is not the one you think it is. You can check this with [getcwd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php). To fix it you can use:

Introduced in 5.3.0:

```
include __DIR__ . '/functions.php';
```

Or

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/functions.php';
```

Comment: Hey guys!

I got it! I cut the function out and put it in the very beginning of functions.php and it works. So there had to be a mistake in a function that was in front of countServices().
And indeed there was a function where the "}" was missing.

Stupid mistake from my side -.-

But thank you all for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this at the top in file.php

`echo '<pre>';

print_r($_SERVER);

echo '</pre>';`

Search for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to see where it points.

Then try to include your functions.php like

`include_once $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '/some-upper-folders/functions.php';`

Comment: In $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] stands the path from folder 'htdocs' to "file.php" (I mentioned in my question).
What I have to put in my code to include functions.php?

Comment: It does not work  with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = .../functions.php anyway

Comment: Hey guys!

I got it! I cut the function out and put it in the very beginning of functions.php and it works. So there had to be a mistake in a function that was in front of countServices().
And indeed there was a function where the "}" was missing.

Stupid mistake from my side -.-

But thank you all for trying to help!